# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm doing the following tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html.

When I try to create the array of Strings I get the error in the heading:

> Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration

It appears on the tenth last element.  I thought maybe it was a size issue, so deleted ten, but then it appeared on the tenth last of the new list.
Anyone know what is the cause?

Comment: Need the code to see what's up. And accept previous answers to other questions if they're right :-)

Comment: The code through the link is the exact same as the one i have. Ill put it up if ye want. Can i put up the code here though? Also i dont know what you mean accept answers to other questions if they're right?

Comment: Actually fixed it. Cheers anyway.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer to this question and then, after the waiting period, accept your answer so that if others have the same problems, they can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was building an app using the Notepad tutorial as a starting point.  Referencing the Notepad tutorial, the class constructors are decorated with @Override directives.

One of my @Override was generating the aforementioned error due to an errant semicolon terminating the line.  Removing the semicolon, that is to say "@Override" instead of "@Override;" resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This answer saved me some time. I did a simple mistake placing a semicolon after an annotation, thx!

Comment: Wow, I had the exact same problem. My ";" was at the end of my @Enumerated annotation. Thanks, I was just blind i guess :).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. You might have declared the string array outside the class declaration. Changing that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this Problem, when I by accident declared an Enum with quotation marks

```java
public enum Environment {
    "WINDOWS", "LINUX";
}
```

instead of

```java
public enum Environment {
    WINDOWS, LINUX;
}
```

It took me a while to see that...